# ubuntu 18.04 repository not updating / can't use apt-get (Could not connect to x.x.x.x:8080)

Tags: apt, package-management, proxy

I logged into Ubuntu and ran

`sudo apt-get update`

then

```
Err:1 https ://download.docker .com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080 (10. 10.8.179). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http ://ppa.launchpad .net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080 (10. 10.8.179). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:3 http ://archive.ubuntu .com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080 (10. 10.8.179). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:4 http ://archive.ubuntu .com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080:
Err:5 http ://archive.ubuntu .com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http ://archive.ubuntu .com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080 (10. 10.8.179). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://archive.ubuntu .com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080:
W: Failed to fetch https ://download.docker .com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080 (10. 10.8.179). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad .net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080 (10. 10.8.179). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've deleted all the proxy configurations in environment variables and for apt in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf and /etc/apt/apt.conf, but the error  still appears. Any ideas to fix my Ubuntu apt?

Thank you.

Comment: Where you the one who set the proxy configurations?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen it's gitlab server set up by another person, i've neither installed any software before on this machine nor configured anything related to network

Answer (score 0):

All five errors which you have got, those links have whitespaces between the link, First check all the PPA, which you have added to the system. `ping` them and make sure that they are working, else remove them.

```
Err:1 https ://download.docker .com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080 (10. 10.8.179). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http ://ppa.launchpad .net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080 (10. 10.8.179). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:3 http ://archive.ubuntu .com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080 (10. 10.8.179). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:4 http ://archive.ubuntu .com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080:
Err:5 http ://archive.ubuntu .com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 10. 10.8.179:8080:
```